# I would like to change background of tabPage while it's active

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set customg background to tabPage, but it works only when its not active.

```
<TabItem Header="Камера" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="170" Height="40" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
                <TabItem.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="res/tap.png"/>
                </TabItem.Background>
</TabItem>
```

This works only when tab is not active
https://ibb.co/hD28jVB
How to change brush of tabItem while it's active or on hover?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a trigger? The VM should then be able to cause a change at will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `TabItem` since the default one sets the `Background` property to some static `SolidColorBrushes`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.MouseOver.Border" Color="#7EB4EA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Disabled.Background" Color="#F0F0F0"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Disabled.Border" Color="#D9D9D9"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Right-click on a `TabItem` in design mode in Visual Studio or in Blend and choose `Edit Template->Edit a Copy` to get a copy the default template and then edit it as per your requirements. Look for the setters that sets the `Background` property, e.g.:

```
<Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
```